# problems with pyinstaller and sys.exit()

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to create a .exe file from my python script and I am having several troubles. It is not recognising sys.exit(x) calls and it is prompting them such errors. The error it prompts is the next one:

```
sys.exit(2) 

   SyntaxError: Invalid syntax
```

Does anybody know the source of that error? Is there any other option which works?

**edit**

```
import requests # The REST Client
import json # For serializing and deserializing JSON
import sys
import urllib3
import getpass
import getopt
import argparse
import csv
import datetime
import os.path
import re
for opt, arg in opts:
    #print "*arg* " + opt + " : " + arg
    if opt in ('-h', '--help'):
        print "****************************************************************************************************"
        print "Uso: Fortimanager.py -i <hostname ip[:port]> -v <vdom> -u <username> -p <password> -f <archivo.csv>"
        print ""
        print "  Los datos hacen referencia al  FortiManager "
        print ""
        print "  En caso de no especificar hostname, username y/o password se solicitaran "
        print ""
        print "  -i: hostname o IP del FortiManager, puerto por defecto: 443. "
        print ""
        print "  -a: adom a utilizar, por defecto adom=root "
        print ""
        print "  -p: dejando la opcion en blanco se solicitara el password sin mostrarse en pantalla"
        print ""
        print "  -f: dejando la opcion en blanco se solicitara el nombre de fichero"
        print "      El formato de fichero tiene que ser: User,Pass,Resource,DstInt"
        print "      Las columnas han de tener encabezado con los nombres mencionados"
        print "***************************************************************************************************"
        print "Ejemplos:"
        print "  python Fortimanager.py    "
        print "  python Fortimanager.py -i 192.168.1.99 -a myAdom -u admin -f politics.csv"
        print "  python Fortimanager.py -i 192.168.1.99 -u admin -p password"
        print "  python Fortimanager.py -i 192.168.1.99:8443 -u admin -a myAdom"
        print "***************************************************************************************************"
        sys.exit(2)
```

Comment: how do you do the conversion (command, which modules do you use)?

Comment: I am using the next command: pyinstaller --onefile script.py , I am using the module sys for exitting, as I metioned before. I have tested changing it with os._exit() but I get the same error.

Comment: can you please include a (simpler) version of the script, then we can test it ourselves or see what is going on

Comment: I added you the piece of code that is generating the error

Comment: This code is Python 2. You are getting a syntax error because the code isn't Python 3.

Comment: Yes I have seen that just was a simple chance that were two misyntax before sys.exit calls. Sorry for the fail

Comment: debug with pylint first